# page loader problem

Tags: javascript, loading

i got a problem with loading code. customer wants when clicked an  tag a hidden loader div will be shown and when (by clicked) other page completely loaded the loader will be hidden.

here is the sample code

```
    function pageLoaded(){
  var hideit = document.getElementById("loadUnload");
  hideit.style.display= "none";
}
window.onload = pageLoaded;
function pageUnloaded(){
  var showit = document.getElementById("loadUnload");
  showit.style.display= "block";
}
window.addEventListener("load", pageLoaded, false);
window.addEventListener("unload", pageUnloaded, false);
window.addEventListener("unbeforeunload", pageUnloaded, false);
window.onload = pageLoaded;
function changeClass(elem, classDark,classSelected) {
  for(objIndex = 0; objIndex < elem.parentNode.children.length; objIndex++) {
       var obj = elem.parentNode.children[objIndex];
       if(obj.className == classSelected) obj.className = classDark;
  }
  elem.className = (elem.className == classDark)?classSelected:classDark;
  elem.children[0].children[0].checked = (elem.className == classSelected) ? true : false;
}
function spinner(){
 var lists = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
 var spinnerdiv = document.getElementById("loadUnload");
  for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++)
  {
      lists[i].onclick = function (){
      spinnerdiv.style.display= "block";
      }

  }
}






and the html code is like that


<**div id="loadUnload">
  <**div id="loadingDiv" class="centered"><div class="text">loading...</div></div>
<**/div>
```

Comment: You should **really** use `var` for your loop variables. Otherwise they are global and likely to break as soon as loops with the same loop variable name (e.g. `i`) are nested (even across different functions)!

Comment: my question is that = how can i do this -  when clicked an tag a hidden loader div will be shown and when (by clicked) other page completely loaded the loader will be hidden.

Comment: Your question is essentially incomprehensible. It's not clear what you are trying to achieve or what the problem is.

Comment: Are you looking to toggle the display property of an HTML element by clicking it?

Comment: yes Dana HTML element by clicking and html body load which clicked link gets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use AJAX and [Jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page).  I believe this will be the best approach, and it will solve your problem once you get used to working with it.